# Get specific small string from a bigger one with multiple occurences

Tags: java, android, linux, string

I made an android application that returns to the console some Linux commands.

In this case I want to find my wlan0 ip and my wlan1(when is connected) ip.
I've got the full text returned by `ifconfig` command. The problem is how can get into 2 variables these 2 IPs?
I Tried to substring after `inet` word but there are more than 1 word with `inet`. What is the optimal solution for this?

This is my string :

```
    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 37  bytes 7123 (6.9 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 37  bytes 7123 (6.9 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    p2p0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 xxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether xxxxxx txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 xxxxxxxxxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether xxxxxxx6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1504  bytes 817297 (798.1 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 686  bytes 126080 (123.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Please note that I don't care about :`p2p0` or `lo` section, only wlan0 and wlan1(when is connected).

**What I want is to save 192.168.0.100 into a String ip;**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured out that I can run ifconig wlan0 and return only wlan0 section. But still how can I get only ip from that whole text?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood what you trying but i think [Regular Expressions](https://regexone.com/)
is a possible way to go

Comment: all what I want is to save "192.168.0.100" into a variable